# JQuery set next value from drop-down to default

Tags: jquery, each

I have a dropdown in my PHP code as

```
<option value="dev" label="Development">Development</option>
<option value="staging" label="Staging">Staging</option>
<option value="production" label="Production">Production</option>
```

Now I want to remove the first element say 'Development' and my requirement is such that the immediate next element 'Staging' should take its position(the default position).

The working code to remove the element with 'Development' value is :

```
$("#environment").find("option[value='" + value + "']").attr('disabled', 'disabled').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Now, the non-working code to set the immediate below element as default element is :

```
$("#environment").find("option[key='" + key+1  + "']").attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Isn't it possible to achieve this using key instead of value ?

The overall code is :

```
$.each(d.envlist, function (key, value) {
$("#environment").find("option[value='" + value + "']").attr('disabled', 'disabled').trigger("liszt:updated");
$("#environment").find("option[value='" + key + 1 + "']").attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

Thanks a lot for reading.Please help

Comment: Can you post your entire code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually almost there. Instead of using attr, use prop
    $("#environment").find("option[key='" + key+1  + "']").prop('selected', 'selected').trigger("liszt:updated");

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.
But that aint working as per my requirement. 
See it does removes the 'Development' button only when I click on the drop-down . 
Till that time it shows 'Development' as default value. This is misleading.